Why is it that $\Big|\sum_{k=0}^{N}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(y)}{(k+1)\pi}dy\Big|\leq\sum_{k=0}^{N}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(y)|}{y}dy$
I mean, I know that it is true because by graphing each of the functions for each $N$ gives me that the difference is as small as I want. But why is that? How can I answer to this question? I think this has to do with the fact that $\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(y)|}{y}dy$ is a monotone function, but I don't really know why. Anyone has a hint? Thank you.

I think the integral on the left has to be from $0$ to $(N+1)\pi$.

Notice that $|\sin(x)|$ is $\pi-$periodic. Also, $$\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{x}dx \geq \int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{b}dx, \ \ 0 < a < b < \infty,$$because $1/b \leq 1/x$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Then, $$\left| \sum_{k=0}^N\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(y)}{(k+1)\pi}dy\right| \leq \sum_{k=0}^N\int_0^\pi \frac{|\sin(y)|}{(k+1)\pi}dy = \sum_{k=0}^N\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(y)|}{(k+1)\pi}dy \leq \sum_{k=0}^N\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(y)|}{y}dy.$$

What do you mean with $\sum_{k=0}^{\pi}$?

Sorry, I meant the sum from $0$ to $N$. Edited.

Too long for a comment to an interesting problem.
@user57 gave a nice and simple (after reading it) answer.
Using harmonic numbers, the lhs is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(y)}{(k+1)\pi}\,dy=\frac{2}{\pi }\,H_{N+1}$$
Using the sine integral
$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(y)|}{y}\,dy=(-1)^N \, \text{Si}((n+1) \pi )+2\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-1)^{k+1}\, \text{Si}(k \pi )$$
Using expansions
$$\text{Si}(p\pi)=\frac \pi 2+(-1)^{p+1}\frac 1{p\pi}\left( 1-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 p^2}+\frac{24}{\pi ^4 p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right) \right)$$
$$H_p= \log (p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right)$$ then
$$\text{Si}((k+1) \pi )-\text{Si}(k \pi )\sim (-1)^k \frac{2}{\pi  k}\left(1-\frac{1}{2 k}+\frac{\pi ^2-4}{2 \pi ^2 k^2} -\frac{\pi ^2-6}{2
   \pi ^2 k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right) \right)$$ gives upper and lower bounds for the difference of two consecutive terms.
Combining  all the above
$$\color{blue}{\text{rhs - lhs} \sim \frac{\pi}{2}  \left(1-\frac{1+\log (N)}{N}+ O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right) \right)}$$
I do not see how "the difference is as small as I want" except if there is a typo for the integral appearing in the lhs (as @geetha290krm. wrote in comments).

Wow!! Thanks for your work.
